# Disable a specific woocommerce notice error message

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to remove a specific woocommerce message that appear late in the day when I add a product in the cart but not compelet the chechout
The message is " the item xx  has been removed from your cart because it can no longer be purchased. Please contact us if you need assistance"
I don't know what is the reason for this error message,
But I want to completely remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

After some searching , I found this support ticket on Wordpress.org
[After Purchase, get a WooCommerce Error](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/after-purchase-get-a-woocommerce-error/) 
and found this code

```
function customize_wc_errors( $error ) {
    if ( strpos( $error, 'entfernt' ) !== false ) {
        return '';
    } elseif ( strpos( $error, 'removed' ) !== false ) {
    return '';
    } else {
        return $error; 
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'customize_wc_errors' );
```

hoping to remove that annoying message